# Using textViewShouldBeginEditing more than once

Tags: ios

I can use

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)firstTextView {
    return NO;  
}
```

to stop a `textView` from being edited via the keyboard.

However if I try to use another

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)secondTextView {
    return NO;  
}
```

I get an error for the redefinition of the `textViewShouldBeginEditing`.

I am sure it is something silly I am doing with the delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you precisely what's wrong. You're redefining the method.

The method takes a `UITextView*` as an argument precisely so you can tell which text view is asking the question, so you can tailor your response. Of course if you want to always say `NO` to all text views then you can ignore the parameter. In any case, just delete your duplicate definition and you'll be fine.